# Why can't I reassign a list (passed as a paramater) in a function?

Tags: python, list, variables, mutable

According to my understanding, both functions should have changed `list` since lists are mutable but only foo() did so.

```
def foo(myList):
  myList[0] = 3
  
def bar(myList):
  myList = [3,2,1]

list = [1,2,3]
print(list)

foo(list)
print(list)

bar(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: `myList` is a name for an object. It only exists in the scope of the function. In `bar` you are changing the name, not the list.

Comment: `foo` changes the list in-place, `bar` creates a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the id may help you to understand it:

```py
def foo(myList):
  myList[0] = 3
  print(id(myList))
  
def bar(myList):
  myList = [3,2,1]
  print(id(myList))

list = [1,2,3]
print(list)
print(id(list))

foo(list)
print(list)
print(id(list))

bar(list)
print(list)
print(id(list))
```